# Did SFAuthenticationSession share cookies between apps

Tags: ios, sfauthenticationsession

I am using Single-Sign-On (SSO) to let user login in the iOS app. I implemented the SSO with SFAuthenticationSession. I created another app and implemented the same SSO mechanism that uses the same login URL. I was expecting that the two apps will share the same SFAuthenticationSession  cookies so that the user will not have enter the password again in the second app after having successfully logged-in in the first one. Is it the normal behavior of SFAuthenticationSession to not share the cookies? If yes, that means that it's not possible to implement a SSO mechanism using SFAuthenticationSession? Using normal webviews will solve this problem? I have found a similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569570/sfauthenticationsession-isnt-sharing-cookies-on-the-real-devices) on the forum but the problem was faced on ios 11 beta. Maybe the problem was solved on the meantime?